# How to correctly read JSON data from a file?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

In my simple Web API, I'm working on a controller which reads a JSON file and then has to return the content as a pure JSON string. However, once read, the latter is stained by many **\r**, **\"** and **\n** which, AFAIK, render its direct parsing impossible. I don't really know how to solve this, I tried with some quite dumb `.Replace("\r", "")`, to no avail, as I don't know how to work around `"\""`. I'm stuck and I have no idea what to do.

Can someone please help me? I'm sorry if this has been asked and solved somewhere else, but I could not find an already answered question to solve my issue.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<string> JsonData()
{
    using var reader = new StreamReader("Mocks\\data.json");
    string fileContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    fileContent = fileContent.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\"", "\""); // Doesn't do the job

    return fileContent;
}
```

Here's how it's given out:

```
{\n\r\"name\":\"lloyd\",\n\r\"mydata\":\"somedata\",\n\r\"moredata\"...}
```

I'd like all the formatting stuff to disappear:

```
{
    "name":"lloyd",
    "mydata":"somedata",
    "moredata": ...
}
```

Comment: So you just want to get a string without any `\r`,`\n` and `\"`?Just change to `fileContent.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\"", "");`.

Comment: @Rena If I `Replace("\"", "")` I lose all the " making up the JSON.

Comment: So what is your expected json?Could you share a sample?

Comment: @Rena Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert to object and return it：

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<Object> JsonData()
{         
    var reader = new StreamReader("data.json");
    string fileContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fileContent);
    return data;
}
```